# How to fix Failed to resolve: support-compat

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

**Why not help me?**

In my application I want use **`ButterKnife`** library and I add this library dependencies. But when add this library and when click on **Sync** button.
Not **sync** project and show me error.

**gradle.Build (project) :**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle.build (app) :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohammad.ncistutorial"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

**Error message :**

```
Failed to resolve: support-compat
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your gradle files work in my demo project. Check if you are connected to the internet, and try clean/build the project and run

Comment: I would suggest not using ButterKnife. Use Android Databinding instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try to add depedency line with exclude group of support of app compact.

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1',{
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    })
```

Comment: thanks, work me. but why show me this error? why you add exclude group: 'com.android.support' and fix it? what is this? thanks

Comment: can you say me more info and description ?

Comment: I have facing same problem for some library. This is because our buildToolsVersion is not compatible with their libraries. Libraries have updated their buildToolsVersion and we have not. That's why ithink issue is there. Proper reason is i also don't know.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
   implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc2',{
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check your .gradle file version. Update or change latest gradle version.